# bootstrap carousel for half of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to have a carousel having 2 images/sections (A and B) on the page width. For every change one half must disappear and the second must take its place i.e. the view must be taken by slides B C, then C D, and at last D A again.

1.
[image]
2.
[image]

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I made usual carousel and couldn't figure out this kind of behavior.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question by editing it. Also, read the [ask] page for other hints on how to improve this question.

Comment: Guys I want to make that kind of behavior on my page, how can I put a code here ?